# Put url requested into an iframe using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Hmm, so I have code that loads an iframe on a page called `page2.html`.  The iframe currently loads the homepage of the site (http://mydomain.com).  However, what I would like to do is place any page requested in an iframe as well.

So, like:  `http://mydomain.com/mypage/mysubpage`

This needs to be grabbed from javascript/jquery and handed down into the iframe src value.  This sounds easy enough, however, their is a `global.js` file that is redirecting to another page (page2.html) which than outputs the iframe (loading http://mydomain.com), so I'll need to pass a variable via javascript from the global.js function and put it into the page2.html page somehow to tell it to load the iframe for a different url instead of http://mydomain.com.

What's the best way to do this exactly?  So, if you go here:  http://cdficonnect.org in your desktop pc, you will notice that it loads the page in the iframe, but if you go here:  http://www.cdficonnect.org/#/pages/articles/317 it still loads up the main page into the iframe and not that url.  How to tell it to load up that url and not the main page?

Sounds simple enough, but having problems with implementing it.

Cookie Approach here:

In the redirector script, before it redirects...

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + 
    ((exdays==null) ? "" : ("; expires="+exdate.toUTCString()));
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ";domain=cdficonnect.org";
}

setCookie('curURL', document.URL, 0);
```

In desktop.html, within the head:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
 var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
 for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
 {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
  {
   return unescape(y);
  }
 }
}

var curURL = getCookie('curURL');
$('iframe').attr('src', curURL);
```

This always displays the homepage within the iframe no matter what url I put into the address:  http://cdficonnect.org

Comment: Either put the URL into a cookie, or add it as a query parameter in the redirect URL.

Comment: Have tried the cookie approach, but for some reason the URL isn't properly getting stored in the cookie... strange

Comment: Unless you show your code, we can't help you fix that.

Comment: Updated with code for how I'm setting/getting cookie.

Comment: The problem is that you're setting the cookie in `cdiconnect.com`, and trying to read it in `www.cdiconnect.com`. Since `setCookie` doesn't specify that the cookie should be available in subdomains, it can't read it. Try adding `domain=cdiconnect.com;` to the cookie.

Comment: But that is not the domain.  The domain is `cdficonnect.org`

Comment: Oh well, now I get cookie is `undefined` in the console.

Comment: That was just a typo. The point is that one has www at the beginning, the other doesn't. You need to use the `domain=` option to make the cookie apply to all subdomains, not just an exact match.

Comment: Ok, and so I added:  `document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ";domain=cdficonnect.org";` to the `setCookie` function and still no luck.  Am I missing something else somewhere?  Updated code in question.

Comment: Looks like the domain was a red herring, because cdficonnect.org does an HTTP redirect to www.cdficonnect.org before anything is downloaded. Now I don't know why the cookie isn't being set. I can't seem to debug it because there's no way to stop in the Chrome debugger before the redirect happens.

Comment: Would it help if I temporarily disabled the redirect to `desktop.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using HTML's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) :

In the redirector script, before it redirects...

```
function storeLocal(label,value)
{
  window.localStorage.setItem(label,value);
}

storeLocal('curURL', document.URL);
```

In desktop.html, within the head:

```
function getStorage(label)
{
 return window.localStorage.getItem(label);
}

var curURL = getStorage('curURL');
$('iframe').attr('src', curURL);
```

### working jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RqkUk/

Comment: I have to wait 19 more hours to award the bounty but this is exactly what I needed!!

Comment: @SolomonClosson Glad I could help ! Don't worry, take your time :)

Comment: @SolomonClosson I don't like doing this but if you could please remember about the bounty :D Thank you !

Comment: Thumbs UP, you got it!